# I need help using Cronjob, with Python3 scripts

Tags: cron, cron-task

Okay, so i have 2 python3 scripts.

First: run.py
Second: run.py

I want to run both scripts at startup automatically within Cron Job, and then they should restart automatically every 1 hour.

Before i managed both manually, with the following command:

`python3 /root/script/rindes/run.py`

And then manually stopped it by ALT + C.

First and Second Python scripts is located in two different folders.

I've tried, without any success...

Answer (score 0):

You can use below cron it may help you with success.

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/script/rindes/run.py
```

It will run every hour at 0 min also please confirm the path of python3 in your system via `which python3` and put this output at the place of `/usr/bin/python3`